# Intellisense not working with vs2015 apache cordova - get the following exception "Object reference not set to an instance"

Tags: apache, cordova, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

[To view Exception Click Me ! ----->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z3XX.png)Not sure why Intellisense is not working with Blank Apache cordova projects from Visual Studio 2015 Community edition.
Have tried to check rule against tools-options-texteditor-html-advanced and found exception under each sections. same exception called Object reference not set to an instance was thrown when tried to edit index.html file from the blank apache cordova project.

Comment: Have you tried to repair the visual studio from programs and features panel? Select Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 -> Right click and select change -> after you see the setup program, follow wizard to repair the visual studio. Then do the above steps again to "Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova" as well in programs and features panel.

Comment: Have did as suggested , but still the problem exists